# Refresh Angular 4 binding changes from chrome extension threads

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I am using angular 4 to build an extension that manages chrome bookmarks

and in bookmarkslist.component.ts constructor I called

```
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(t=>this.tree = t)
```

but the callback does not make angular 4 to refresh changes

for test purpos I added a button that add an Item to "tree" array .. and since is called on "i think" the ui thread .. the binding is refreshed and the tree is rendered